# How to match customer name column with worksheet name and return Table total

Tags: vba, excel

My main sheet is named as "Main Summary".  This sheet has three columns.

1. Serial #
2. Customer Name
3. Outstanding Balance

The other sheets are named as "Salman", "Rehman", and "Islam".
Each sheet has one table in them. The table has 5 columns and a total row at the end of it.

I'm trying to match the names in "Customer Name" column with the sheets and then link the last cell of table's total row to the outstanding balance column against the customer name.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub CopyRows() 
  Dim bottomD As Integer 
  bottomD = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

  Dim c As Range 
  Dim ws As Worksheet 

  For Each c In Sheets("all").Range("D2:D" & bottomD) 
    For Each ws In Sheets ws.Activate 
      If ws.Name = c Then 
        c.EntireRow.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
      End If 
    Next ws 
  Next c 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code you need help with?

Comment: Sub CopyRows()
Dim bottomD As Integer
bottomD = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each c In Sheets("all").Range("D2:D" & bottomD)
For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Activate
If ws.Name = c Then
c.EntireRow.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If
Next ws
Next c
End Sub

Comment: The problem is that i am working with the tables and i want the last cell of total row to be linked with the main summary sheet

Comment: Put the code and explanation in your original post

Comment: I have posted in the main post

Comment: I don't see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, your solution is incredibly iterative where it doesn't need to be. Also your explanation doesn't entirely match your code. You reference `Column B` in your question and your code looks at `Column D`. You also talk about a sheet named `Main Summary` and your code references `all`

You loop through all the cells, and then the sheets as well where in fact you could just declare the sheet and use one loop

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim all As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set all = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Summary")
    With all
        Set rng = Range("D2:D" & .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each c In rng
        ' By using error handling you can avoid using a second loop
        On Error GoTo ContinueLoop
        Set ws = Sheets(c.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0

        c.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=" & ws.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#Totals],[Balance]]"
ContinueLoop:
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: i have a table in my other sheet. I want the last cell of total row to be linked on the "Main Summary" Sheet infront of the customer name instead of "c.EntireRow.Copy Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)".

Comment: @SalmanKhan Sorry can you update your question with more information. Where is the total row and what is the structure of the "Main Summary" sheet. You have eluded these details completely.

Comment: i have updated the post. "Salman" Rehman" and "iSlam" are the customers.

Comment: You removed your code? Was that even relevant to your question? At this point in time I'm going to refer you to [this, please update your question following these guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No that can only be used if i use the range instead of tables.

Comment: What's the name of the column in which the totals are?

Comment: The name of the column is Balance

Comment: You could just use a formula to get this out. I've updated my answer though to add it dynamically. This will 'link' the two cells as you put it

Comment: Thank You Tom it works. You helped me a lot and thanks for it.